# Trying to use perl Math::GSL::ODEIV

Tags: perl, math, ode, gsl

I am trying to use the perl module [Math::GSL::ODEIV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::GSL::ODEIV) - the perl interface to the Gnu Scientific Library. I can follow the example given in the GSL docs to solve the van der Pol diff. Equation. However I am unable to see how to translate to the perl module functions. Has anyone used this module? If so, can I see some example perl code?

Comment: Needs more information. Sample input and expected output, C code you're trying to translate to perl, what you've tried, etc.

Comment: Judged by the docs the interface should be "the same" as in the library, so you'd have to tweak things around in Perl.  If you show us your code that isn't working then somebody may be able to help

Comment: Note, it seems `Math::GSL::ODEIV` only supports the old ODEIV library. If you want to use the new ODEIV2 library, see the module [PerlGSL::DiffEq](https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlGSL::DiffEq)